# How to design in xml like below image in android?

Tags: android, xml, androiddesignsupport

How to design in xml like below `image` in android.

[image]

Comment: Use a FrameLayout

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please learn asking good questions 
stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is this xml design for custom dialog??

Answer (score 0):

Gradle:

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="#808080">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:text="TEST TEXT"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_test"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution i have use for custom dialog

--

```
Dialog  mDlg = new Dialog(SplashActivity.this);
        mDlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mDlg.setContentView(R.layout.layout_head_dialog);
        mDlg.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        mDlg.show();
```

XML Design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorTransparent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorTransparent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBlackFaint"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="24dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Custom Dialog"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/topImg"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_view"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_offf"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Output Like This

[image]